# Connect UI elements to a slot in array

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch

I have 7 switches from Monday to Sunday, and need to connect all 7 switches to my controller. It feels really awkward to connect them separately:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic)IBOutlet UISwitch *switch1;
@property (strong, nonatomic)IBOutlet UISwitch *switch2;
@property (strong, nonatomic)IBOutlet UISwitch *switch3;
...
@property (strong, nonatomic)IBOutlet UISwitch *switch7;
// It gets worse when you have even more switches
```

Instead, is it possible to have an `NSArray *switchArr` that holds 7 switches, and we connect switch 1 to switchArr[1], switch 2 to switchArr[2], and so on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on the single switch in the IB and drag from "New Referencing Outlet Collection" to your .h file to create a new outlet collection. You should see a property

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UISwitch) NSArray *switches;
```

created. Repeat dragging every other switch to that property.

Comment: Is the order preserved? For example, if I connect in order `1,2,3,4`, does it necessarily make `1` connected to slot `0` in the array?

Comment: Not 100% sure, but you can always use a tag for each switch.

Comment: What do you mean use a tag for each switch?

Comment: In the attributes inspector, you can set a property "tag" for each switch, from 0 - 6. Then you can access this when you iterate the switches array to determine which switch you are accessing by calling switch.tag. Also check out viewWithTag method on UIView. But be careful, 0 is the default value, so it may return some random subview :)

Comment: I would like to add this : set a tag for each switch and in viewDidLoad sort your array based on the tag

Answer (score 1):

set a tag for each switch in the order you want the switches to be within the array, you can start tagging from 10 to avoid conflicts with other views and then in your viewDidLoad you can store the views into a mutable array, something like this:

```
NSMutableArray *switches = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSInteger initialTag = 10; //set your initial tag
for(NSInteger i = initialTag; i < initialTag + 7; i++) {
    [switches addObject:[self.view viewWithTag:i]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can do something like this

```
@property (strong, nonatomic)IBOutletCollection(UISwitch) NSArray * switches;
```